# Export a SSRS 2005 report in XML to PDF

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I'm using C# with ASP.NET(2.5) and SQL Server 2005.

I have an SSRS 2005 Report (*.rdl) stored in a varbinary field in the database, and I need to generate a report (in PDF or image file) and send it by e-mail, with some parameters. The CRUD part is OK, but I can't generate the report and export to PDF from an XML string (that I get from the varbinary field).

I don't have any code to give to you folks (sorry). I tried lots of tutorials from the web and none of them suited for me. I also searched here in stack overflow and didn't find anything.

Note 1: I know how to do it from a file stored in a hard drive, for example. I don't want to save the file I get from the varbinary field in the hard drive and generate the report from it. I want to generate the report from the XML string stored in a variable.

Note 2: I'm new to C#, and have another silly question: Crystal Report (*.rpt) and SSRS (*.rdl) are different files (different XML structures), right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, in answer to Note 2, Crystal Reports and SSRS are competitors, so yes, the formats are different.

Secondly, you want to use the [`ReportExecutionService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc282506.aspx) class. If you have any report parameters to set, use [`SetExecutionParameters()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.setexecutionparameters.aspx) and [`Render()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render.aspx) with `Format=PDF`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked almost perfectly. I need to "deploy" the Report on the hard drive, but after that it worked well.

Comment: Sorry, not enough reputation... :/